# I need to implement Notification Reminder in my android app

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, reminders

**My Requirment:** I want my application to show a reminder notification on every Friday @ 8 am

I have used AlarmManager, BroadcastReceivers to implement my reminder notification. The problem I am getting is, When I set notification time using current system time and Add 2 minutes in it... It works perfectly when I use it in this way, it trigger my notification exactly after 2 minutes.

But,

When I use calender instance to set notification time at specific time of any day, it trigger my reminder notification when ever I start/open my app on my device/emulator and secondly it wont trigger notification at specified time

Following are my classes

Here is my HomeActivity.java

```
// long when = System.currentTimeMillis()+2*60*1000;         // notification time
// WHEN I RUN THE ABOVE COMMENTED CODE… THE REMINDER IS TRIGGERD AFTER EXACTLY 2 MINS
//BUT WHEN I USE THE BELOW CODE USING CALENDER INSTANCE, IT TRIGGER MY REMINDER    IMMIDIETLY WHEN I RUN IT ON MY DEVICE/EMULATOR


    Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();            
    //calendar.set(2014,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),Calendar.SUNDAY , 8, 00, 00);
    calendar.set(2014,5,1,19,55,00);
long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();         // notification time


Log.d("time", when+" ");

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

// create the object
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 //set the alarm for particular time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Here is my AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.myapp.app;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
        if(dayOfWeek != 5 && dayOfWeek != 7) {
            Notification.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Here is my Title")
                    .setContentText("Here is my text");
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

I’ve added following in manifest

```
<receiver
android:name="com.myapp.app.AlarmReceiver"
/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help... :)

Comment: Your `calendar.set` is in the past.  The commented-out `calendar.set` uses the day of month as Sunday which comes out as 1, so it's always on the first of the respective month (and will be off after 2014).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `setRepeating` to repeat your alarm every week.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, when, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

P.S. Don't set the year. Otherwise, your alarm will trigger only once.